# Calculate percentage with up to two digits after the dot

Tags: javascript

How to calculate percentage and have up to two digits after the dot? Based on **previous topic**, I tried the following:

```
function calc(part, whole) {
    if (!whole)
        return 0.00;
    return parseFloat((100 * part/whole).toFixed(2));
}
```

But what I get:

```
console.log((100 * 11154/48291).toFixed(2)) // 23.10
console.log((100 * 11154/48291))  // 23.09747157855501
```

I want the final result to be `23.09` and not `23.10`. Also I want to return a number and not a string. the `toFixed()` method rounds up and returns a string. How should I do it? Maybe lodash can help me somehow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Round to at most 2 decimal places (only if necessary)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary)

Comment: @esqew that's the one I tried to use.  All of them round the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
Math.trunc((100 * part/whole) * 100)/100;
console.log(Math.trunc(100 * 11154/48291 *100)/100)  // 23.09
```

But if the number is negative Math.trunc will not round down.

More about [Math.trunc](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Math/trunc)

Comment: Why it's not clear? I prefer not to use 'not clear solutions'

Comment: Because it can have a different behavior when the number is negative due to the way Math.trunc works.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
function calc(part, whole) {
    if (!whole)
        return 0.00;

    const valueStr = parseFloat((100 * part/whole)).toString();
    const dot = valueStr.indexOf('.');

    if(dot !== -1) {
      return Number(valueStr.slice(0, dot + 3));
    } else {
      return Number(valueStr);
    }
}

//testing
console.log(calc(23,45));
console.log(calc(83,23))
console.log(calc(12,12))
console.log(calc(14,76))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use that function to do the trick

```
function trunc_to_precision(number, precision) {
  numberAsStr = number.toString();
  if (!numberAsStr.includes('.')) {
    return number;
  }

  let [entier, decimal] = numberAsStr.split('.');

  return parseFloat(entier + '.' + decimal.substring(0,precision));
}

let x = trunc_to_precision(23.09747157855501, 2); // 23.09 as float
```